# Canvas image sinks in to edges on collison

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

As you can see when running the code, the collision is off. The side of the image keeps sinking into the edge of the canvas, i have tried to minus the image size from canvas height in the draw(); function but it stops the image from showing.

Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

console.log($(document).height());
console.log($(document).width());
console.log($("#img").height());
console.log($("#img").width());

var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height-30;
var dx = 5;
var dy = -5;
var img = document.getElementById("img");
var $imgHeight = $("#img").height();
var $imgWidth = $("#img").width();

function draw(){
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source:over";
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        ctx.drawImage(img,x,y,120,150);

        if(x + dx > canvas.width || x + dx < 120){
            dx = -dx;
        }
        if(y + dy > canvas.height || y + dy < 150){
            dy = -dy;
        }
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Game</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1416" height="702"></canvas>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <!--<img src="url.jpg" id="img" width="120" height="150">-->
  <img src="http://orig05.deviantart.net/7a06/f/2015/207/b/c/ainsley_s_face_by_lordfriezypop-d92vofk.jpg" id="img" width="120" height="150">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is jsfiddle if needed: https://jsfiddle.net/16oxobkt/

Comment: because `y` is the top position of your image,  you have to check for `y + imgHeight` if you want to check for its bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it:

```
if(x + dx > canvas.width - $imgWidth ||  x + dx < 0){
        dx = -dx;
}
if(y + dy > canvas.height - $imgHeight || y + dy < 0){
        dy = -dy;
}
x += dx;
y += dy;
```

The image's coordinates are on the top left part of the image so:

If the image goes to the edge of the screen on the left where x = 0 if `x + dx < 0` then the velocity switches. However if the image goes to the far right of the screen it will sink in unless you make the velocity switch when it reaches the coords of `canvas.width - $imgHeight` as you can see here: `x + dx > canvas.width - $imgWidth`. This stops the image from sinking in to the side of the canvas and the same applies to the Y axis: `y + dy > canvas.height - $imgHeight`,  `y + dy < 0`